# Closest nodes with Locations and Views

Tags: 7, views, location

I'm using Drupal 7 with Views 3 module and Location 3 module installed.

I have a content type that has a Location type field and I would like to build a view that given a latitude/longitude input and a maximum distance i have to retrieve all the nodes that are in this range. Is that possible with views or I have to build something by my own (in this case can you show me the way on how to implement it).

Thanks a lot for your help

Danilo

### **Resuming the question problem is the following:**

I have a problem setting a View to show the closest nodes of another (I'm using last dev version of views and locations on drupal 7). So my scenario is the following:
I have 2 differents node types (A and B) both with a location field. I want to build a view that given a node A (with a determinate location) a have to retreive all the nodes B in a distance of 2Km.
So to do that I created a view with the following filters:

1. Content: Type = B
2. Location: Distance / Proximity, with the parameters

   - {origin:"node's lat/lon from views nid argument"}
   - {Node ID argument to use: (it doesnt allow me to select any data)}
   - {Location to use:"CCK Location: field_A_loc"}.

I also added a contextual filter. I selected as contextual filter:

- {Content: Nid}

and I added % to my path so now the pat is /myviewpath/%. This allow me to choose the value:

- {Content: Nid} in the field "Node ID argument to use" of the filter "Location: Distance / Proximity".

So i try to run the view but I get no results when the view is called as mydomain.com/myviewpath/3 where 3 is a A node.

I also tried to do not use the contextual filter (that does not allow me to set the "Node ID argument to use" in the "Location: Distance / Proximity, with the parameters" filter) and running the view mydomain.com/myviewpath/node/3 but in this case I get the list of all B nodes..

What I'm doing wrong setting up this view??

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could set up a view, filtering on Location: Distance / Proximity, and configure what the origin or "starting point" is, eg, the location of the logged in user, a node that has a location, or, in this case, a static lat/long, and then have it display whatever fields in the filtered nodes you want.

Comment: Distance / Proximity are available as filters for Views with Location 3 installed?

Comment: Thanks jimajamma I setted the filter with Location: Distance / Proximity. But I dont have any contextual filter to set the lat/long dinamicaly.

Comment: If you need to dynamically set the origin lat/long, you can use the USE PHP TO DETERMINE LATITUDE/LONGITUDE option in the filter to create the coordinate anyway you want.

Comment: Citricguy, yes, but it's not magic. you need to have set/entered a location for your users and/or nodes for it to have any effect.  That's why there is a filter "Location ID" you can filter on "not empty" so you can filter out any users or nodes that haven't had it set.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma, if I have 2 different node types (A and B) both with a location filter. I want to build a view that given a node A (with a determinate location) a have to retreive all the nodes B in a distance of 2Km. I created a view with the following filters:(1) Content: Type = B (2) Location: Distance / Proximity, with the parameters{origin:"node's lat/lon from views nid argument"}{Node ID argument to use: (it doesnt allow me to select any data)}{Location to use:"CCK Location: field_A_loc"}.

Comment: So i try to run the view passing the node id as argument to the view -> mydomain.com/view-name/node/3 where the node with id 3 is a A type. But my view it does not show the correct results, all the nodes B are showed. Any Idea on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: you seem to be doing this right as you do this by passing the node's nid as an argument to the view.  if it were a page display, you could do it something like path/to/my/view/% and then % would be the nid, eg, path/to/my/view/27 would pass node 27 in.  if it were within a block on a node page, you could pass the nid in from the block the view is looking at.  this is all described within the argument area.  so, check to make sure you are doing the proximity right and restricting it to only all those nodes.

Comment: also, add a filter to the view that checks to make sure there is a location id (lid) in the node in question.  the default behavior could be to include locationless nodes, I don't remember.

Comment: I'm using views 3 with D7 so there are no arguments to select in the views UI so I selected as contextual filter: {Content: Nid}, and I added % to my path so now the pat is /myviewpath/%. This allow me to choose the value Content: Nid in the field "Node ID argument to use" of the filter "Location: Distance / Proximity". I also tried to set some custom view to be sure that the lat lon of the various node types are ok and so they are.

Comment: I get no results when the view is called as mydomain.com/myviewpath/3

Answer (score 0):

Think the best docs are now up https://drupal.org/node/1944648

Answer (score 0):

By doing what you specified the view will show all nodes next to the visited node, as you added a contextual filter.
Moreover, **make sure to tick Exclude box in More section from {Content: Nid} field in contextual filter.**
This tutorial may be helpful
https://www.reinisfischer.com/how-create-drupal-views-distance-filter-using-location-module